# iOS Managing Domain Model and NSManagedObject Model

Tags: ios, core-data, domain-model

I would like to know how can we manage our domain Model and NSManagedObject Model. My scenario is I have to show last 5 comments from coredata which I fetch from coredata manager class, and it returns 5 objects of Comments (:NSManagedObject) object. now I want to to fetch next n number of comments from our server API and will parse them into my domain model object Comments( inherited from NSObject).

Now I have two types of object which logically represents the same object. I want to know best practice/design pattern, how we should handle/implement this.

One obvious solution is to loop through NSManagedObject Model and populate 5 new models of my domain object derived from NSObject and then continue to fetch these objects from my APIManager class. But I want to know the best way if there it is any.

Comment: Why you have 2 types of comments? You should use the same nsmanagedobject for all the data handling. But use a view model copy of them for ui.

Comment: I just want to save first 5 comments, user can load 100 more(if any) from server but they won't be cached, so why I should save them in NSManagedObject class?

Comment: Then you need to remove the first 5 comments each time and replace them with new coredata objects ? That sounds like a lot of work. I guess why using coredata at all then. You could implement a memory cache that keeps only the last 5 comments in memory and serialize it to disk. Coredata is good if you need to handle many many many objects and you need performances on ui updates. In your case a memory object is enough maybe. Coredata is way more complicated and risky (for thread safety etc).

Comment: Do you need to show these comments offline? Maybe you can skip persistence at all and just store in memory. You can retrieve your comments from api at each launch of the app. So that they are never stale

Comment: yes I need show these comments offline, and core data is used to save feeds and user connections offline, and user can also perform some actions while offline and those will b updated when user goes online.

Comment: You could still store more than 5 and show the last 5.  Then have a helper cleaning coredata from old

Comment: won't it be little inefficient ?

Comment: IMHO Coredata is made on purpose to store and easily retrieve thousands of objects without impacting performances. How are you planning on deleting them today? Select the entire series and mark it to be deleted before inserting all the others? That could make sense too

Answer (score 0):

First of all, CoreData is not thread safe, so don’t use those comments objects into the controllers or the views. Isolate core data in a separate layer and transform these objects into a view model or some other form of immutable struct for the view.

Second, you can use a nsfetched result controller in a “provider” class to keep you informed automatically of what are the last 5 comments. A delegate can inform your view of when this provider data change.

You can refresh your server data in background with your api ma manager and when you get the data back, store them in coredata. If you used a nsfetched result controller, you won’t need to do anything else as coredata will automatically notify the object you setup to return you comments